# How to switch between legacy and new app using YARP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms, .net-5, ms-yarp

I have a legacy Asp.Net Web forms app which I'm migrating to .net 5. I'm trying to migrate this piece by piece. I'm using Microsoft YARP as reverse proxy - https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy which helps to retarget URLs of old application to new application without users knowing it. So this first part is done.

But now I'm facing issues where users are finding critical issues in new app and this is becoming hard to handle. So I was thinking to implement a link/button on the pages which will allow users to use legacy or new app as needed. I have seen many websites which allow to switch between classic and new version of their websites. But not sure, how should I approach this with YARP. As I see YARP configuration gets applied to all users and it is kind of static. It can be reloaded, though. In my case, User-A may want to use a page from legacy app and User-B may want to use it from new app.

I read on their site that I can write an middleware to handle custom logic but not sure how to approach this. Any guidance will be more than helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [migration assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) from Microsoft incremental migration [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/incremental-asp-net-to-asp-net-core-migration/)  to auto-setup a YARP reverse proxy.

Don't forget edit on appsettings.json, the property fallBackApp on ReverseProxy section after deploying your .NET Core application .